# RewriteCond to exclude a directory and it's sub-directories

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've been trying to get a wikipedia style language thing to work. So that the url will be `en.example.com` for English, `fr.example.com` for French, etc... This is working fine however I would like the admin area to always default to base language, i.e. not set the LANGUAGE environment variable. I've tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin [NC]` but it seems to have no effect.

My mod_rewrite code is as follows:

```
# Handle languages 
# Picks up the language code from the browser accept-language parameter
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2}).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2,}\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.[a-z]{2,}\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [ENV=LANGUAGE:%1,QSA]

# Redirecting all requests to one script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([\+a-zA-Z0-9,%\(\)\_\ -/]+)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks for any help, I'm sure it's something really stupid that is wrong, as usual.

Comment: Please try to reformat your 'code' around a code block

Comment: ok, how's that... it's odd because it looked fine in the preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that REQUEST_URI doesn't start with admin, its going to have a slash in front... it might start with /admin if you have no rewrite base... so you can change it to !^/admin or just !admin or !admin/ if all your code is in foo.com/admin/*

REQUEST_URI is going to be the entire GET like "/foo/bar.html"

Comment: I've tried all of those. I, also, assumed that it would start with a /. However none of them seem to stop the language variable being set, it's as if the `RewriteCond` ignored, or never seems to match.
There is no code in /admin/ the whole structure is imaginary

Comment: Why don't you try something simpler... such as 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?not_admin=1 [R, L]
If it redirects when you have admin in there, and doesn't when you don't have admin in there then the rule is working fine... maybe you need to blindly set the language environment variable to the default first, maybe its keeping its value from the last process since they are re-used threads ?

Comment: I think you're correct about it keeping it's value from the last process, the rule does seem to work, if I remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [ENV=LANGUAGE:%1,QSA]` the RewriteRule below (`RewriteRule ^([\+a-zA-Z0-9,%\(\)\_\ -/]+)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]`) doesn't run. Looks like i might have to detect that's in admin with PHP